# sock.settimeout(timeout) TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python

Trying to write something that'll take the parameter 'name' which will be a players name, find a few stats for him and print them.  I got it to work when I was using the player's specific URL, but trying to turn it into a function is presenting some difficulty.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def statGet(name):
    binary = name.encode('ascii')
    html = urlopen("http://www.nba.com/playerfile/",binary,'/')
    print(html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    pts = soup.find("td", {"class": "PTS"})
    reb = soup.find("td", {"class": "REB"})
    ast = soup.find("td", {"class": "AST"})
    stats = pts.get_text(), reb.get_text(), ast.get_text()
    print('Points per game:',stats[0])
    print('Rebounds per game:',stats[1])
    print('Assists per game:',stats[2])

statGet('quincy_acy')
```

I would expect that to get the stats for Quincy Acy, but instead I get an unexpected error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
TypeError: a float is required
```

I assume this is a problem with the socket.py module, which through some googling I was able to find out was a socket wrapper, but not what this error means or how to fix it.  Any ideas?  I've tried different encodings, etc. but nothing I've tried works so far.

Comment: The third argument of urlopen is timeout, in this case it's `'/'`.

Comment: Why are you encoding `name`? `urlopen("http://www.nba.com/playerfile/" + name)` should work.

Comment: @vaultah , thank you so much!